# IOS app icon is not showing using flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-launcher-icons

So I'm facing problem to set IOS app icon in simulator as well as physical device. I have created my own custom app icon for flutter application. also I have used flutter third party library **flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1** in ***dev_dependencies*** in ***pubspec.yaml*** file to generate and set app icon in both android and ios. I have also added below path into ***dev_dependencies***:

```
flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/Launcher_Icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 19 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
  web:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/images/Launcher_Icon.png"
    background_color: "#FFFFFF"
#    theme_color: "#hexcode"
  windows:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/images/Launcher_Icon.png"
    icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48
  macos:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/images/Launcher_Icon.png"
```

after that I have execute `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons` command to generate icons and that gives me following output:

```
Deprecated. Use `dart run` instead.
Building package executable... (7.0s)
Built flutter_launcher_icons:main.
This command is deprecated and replaced with "flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons"
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
     FLUTTER LAUNCHER ICONS (v0.13.1)                               
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
  
• Creating default icons Android
• Adding a new Android launcher icon
• Overwriting default iOS launcher icon with new icon
Creating Icons for Web...              done
Creating Icons for Windows...          done
Creating Icons for MacOS...            done

✓ Successfully generated launcher icons
```

Below are the Screen Shots of Runner Structure and warnings:

1 -> [image]

2 -> [image]

3 -> [image]

4 -> [image]

Though it didn't work for me.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to use that.
Use 'https://icon.kitchen' instead of that.

Comment: @rasityilmaz where i need to put ios icon? inside **AppIcon.appiconset** right?

Comment: Yes  inside AppIcon.appiconset